# Basic Robot Methods? (turn_degrees, drive_cm, dist traveled)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How best to achieve the following basic robot methods in ROS2 (foxy and galactic both):

- turn_degrees()  --> pub /cmd_vel until /odom heading change achieved?
- drive_cm()        --> pub /cmd_vel until /odom x change achieved?
- log distance traveled by robot  --> (sum of absolute value of average of left and right encoder changes)?

Or are there ROS2 packages that implement these as services or actions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389979/basic-robot-methods?--(turn_degrees,-drive_cm,-dist-traveled)/) by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2021-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-03**:
I'm not aware of any packages specifically, but perhaps Nav2 can be configured such that it could do these things @stevemacenski (it's a bit overkill, but would be the easiest to scale up to actual navigation)?.

Alternatively: this sounds like a basic position controller closing the loop over the `/odom` topic with `Twist`s going to `/cmd_vel` indeed.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-11-08**:
Nav2 would be overkill, these would all be trivial to implement in an hour a piece or less.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-09**:
It would be overkill, but allow for a seamless transition to more complex planning problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As no one pointed me to anything specific, I chose to tackle building a "Robot Independent" odometer node in discrete Python by watching the /odom topic for start and end of motion and tallying the 3D distance traveled of each update between the start and end of motion.  (I learned that not all robots publish encoders on the same topic and message format, where most are publishing odometry using a standard message format.)

After the fact, I found this code example (publishing the distance where I am using Python logging out to a file):

https://www.theconstructsim.com/ros-qa-195-how-to-know-if-robot-has-moved-one-meter-using-odometry/

Perhaps if my bagging skills were better I would log the distance segments to a topic and bag them to an odometer bag.

The other two methods, drive_cm() and turn_degrees() are indeed easy to implement but as mapping and navigation are next on my learning path, I expect I will find the "ROS way" for these I am sure someone has coded before.

---

Originally posted by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) with karma: 327 on 2021-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0